# IE10 font size is off by 1px. How to fix?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Because it is just 1px I can't tell if it is the text box next to the button or the button itself.  So I was going to take a screenshot and look at it with a measuring tool.  From there I was going to look the firefox debugger and ie debugger to see what is off by 1px.

However I was hoping someone might have an idea to what is causing this.

Here is the offending element in ie ( 28 px )

[image]

Here is where it is correctly displayed in FF, Chrome, etc. ( 27 px )

[image]

http://www.arcmarks.com

Here is the CSS for the button:

```
#ue_but_new{
  position: absolute;
  padding:  8px 6px 7px 6px;
  text-decoration:  none;
  cursor:  pointer;
}

p.small_white{
  font-size:    10px;
  color:        #ffffff;
}

.blue_but{
  color:       #ffffff;
  border:      1px solid #057ed0;
  background:  -moz-linear-gradient(top, #31baed, #019ad2);
}
```

Comment: You can press F12 to load your developer tools, and then inspect both elements in the Layout tab to determine their dimensions. As of Internet Explorer 11, you can right click an element and select "Inspect Element".

Comment: Give us your relevant code

Comment: Looks fine to me in IE10 on Windows 7 and 8 (http://i.imgur.com/fVJ2XDf.png). Your site, however, is broken in Internet Explorer 11 (http://i.imgur.com/UvNVWOy.png). You really should avoid browser detection scripts.

Comment: I found that the button is 28 px tall in IE 10 and 27px tall in other browses....

Comment: @www.arcmarks.com Did you give an explicit height to the button, or is the height determined only by line-height, font-size, padding and borders?

Comment: This is an IE bug, If you add up the parameters, you get 10px (text) + 8px(padding-top) + 7px(padding-bottom) + 1px(border top) + 1px(border bottom) = 27px.

Comment: How can I file this bug against IE10?  Their numbers don't add up even in their own debugger!

Answer (score 1):

If you base element size on text size, it will always vary between different browsers, different systems, different settings, et.c.

Set a specific line height on the element instead of padding from the text height:

```
#ue_but_new{
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 25px;
  padding: 0 6px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: @www.arcmarks.com: The font size is not the same as the height of the text. In most cases it will just end up as the same value, because of the settings of the font and the way that the font is rendered. The line height will always be exactly what you set it, as it's not affected by the font size or how the font is rendered.

Comment: @www.arcmarks.com: The font size is a real dimension, but it's not the height of the font, it's actually the width of the font. A font is measured in em units, which was original the width of the capital M character. The unit is points, but the browser lets you specify this in pixels instead, which is then translated to points. So, in the end it's more of a coincidence that the pixel size of the font happens to correspond so well to the font height in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to apply border on the input & button wrapper, then set overflow:hidden.
This way, even if it's off by a pixel, it's not visible.

In HTML:

```
<div>
  <input type="" />
  <button></button>
</div>
```

In CSS (roughly):

```
div {
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius:3px;
  background:#fff;
  overflow:hidden;
}
input {
  border:0;
  background:transparent;
}
button {
  background:blue;
}
div, input, button { height:22px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefer setting the `line-height` property to vertically center a single line of text rather than using `padding-bottom` and `padding-top`.

In your case `font-size: 10px` + `padding-top: 8px` + `padding-bottom: 7px` = `line-height: 25px`.

```
#ue_but_new {
    position: absolute;
    padding:  0 6px;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-decoration:  none;
    cursor:  pointer;
}
```